# How can I make two objects comparable

Tags: go

I'm passing objects of two different structs to a function where it's compared with an existing object saved as `interface {}` type.

In the following how can I make two objects comparable for Equality `===`

In this attempt, comparison with bar works fine but with foo it throws a panic error in spite both objects are of struct type

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mPQTTzz9QD)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    TestMethod func(str string)
}

type Bar struct {}

type IQux interface {
    Compare(object interface{}) bool
}

type Qux struct {
    Method func(str string)
    Reference interface{}
}

func (qux Qux) Compare(object interface{}) bool {
    return object == qux.Reference
}

func testMethod(str string) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{TestMethod:testMethod}
    bar := Bar{}

    ob := &Qux{Method: foo.TestMethod, Reference: foo}

    ob.Compare(bar) // works fine
    ob.Compare(foo) // panic: runtime error: comparing uncomparable type main.Foo
}
```

Comment: The definition of comparable is set in the language specification: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators. How do you want to compare them?

Comment: do I've to implement foo and bar with some interface?

Comment: There's no interface for comparison, what can be compared is listed in the specification I linked. If you want to compare in some other way, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: I read but I couldn't understand, I'm comparing on line 21 `object == qux.Reference` with equality operator, how can I have a fix for the above code please?

Comment: @JimB I'm new to go language, kindly enlighten. It works with bar but fails with foo

Comment: From the docs linked by JimB: "Struct values are comparable if **all their fields are comparable**." Functions are not comparable, so the field TestMethod causes the panic.

Comment: the types are not comparable, so I don't understand how you want to compare them. You could use `reflect.DeepEqual` to avoid the panic, but I'm not sure if that does what you want either.

Comment: I tried reflect but didn't work, for instance `reflect.DeepEqual(foo, foo)` returns false whereas it should return true, I want to compare if both references are the same object, like `===` operator in other languages

Comment: @User794691: they can't be the same object, because you are comparing copies of their values. If you want to see if they are the same object, you need to use pointers.

Comment: @User794691 If you remove the function field, your panic goes away https://play.golang.org/p/jwLA3L5qbc. In Go you cannot compare functions.

Comment: JimB that makes sense, can you please show with the code

Comment: @mkopriva I need to have method there, in fact you can add the same method signature to Bar as well but problem persists. The reason it worked because interface{} defined in Qux is an empty body construct so any struct with empty body works

Comment: @User794691: note that field is _not_ a method, it's a function value and doesn't contribute to the method set. If you want to compare pointers,  you need to use a pointer: https://play.golang.org/p/s1tXO1sxgp

Comment: Brave @JimB. please add as an answer so I can mark it correct

Comment: @User794691: again, this doesn't seem useful; are you sure this is what you're trying to do? https://play.golang.org/p/JHkkYXj1uo

Comment: @User794691 your `structs` don't have to be empty to be comparable, they just need to have fields that themselves are comparable, which functions in Go are not. https://play.golang.org/p/3w_CQXXIGn. But yeah, if you need that `func` to be a field instead of a real method, then you can use pointers to check if it's the same instance, as JimB demonstrated, but you still won't be able to compare two instances. https://play.golang.org/p/CDVrvkWyoD

Comment: @JimB your link https://play.golang.org/p/s1tXO1sxgp worked for my needs

Comment: @mkopriva in your link, why f3 is not same, all of them looked same to me, I'm surprised.

Comment: it has uppercase "F" in the string

Comment: @JimB I think I got confused it with the error comparable here, it should be how to check equality of two objects, and your answer that I've to apply `==` equality operator on the pointers instead of copy/value of objects, that was the mistake.

Comment: Thanks @JimB and mkopriva

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a little typo, just try:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    TestMethod func(str string)
}

type Bar struct {}

type IQux interface {
    Compare(object interface{}) bool
}

type Qux struct {
    Method func(str string)
    Reference interface{}
}

func (qux Qux) Compare(object interface{}) bool {
    return object == qux.Reference
}

func testMethod(str string) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func main() {
    foo := &Foo{TestMethod:testMethod}
    bar := Bar{}

    ob := Qux{Method: foo.TestMethod, Reference: foo}

    ob.Compare(bar) // works fine
    ob.Compare(foo) // panic: runtime error: comparing uncomparable type main.Foo
}
```